# How to get UITouch location from UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I want to get the UITouch location of my tap from UIGestureRecognizer, but I can not figure out how to from looking at both the documentation and other SO questions. Can one of you guide me?

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    CCLOG(@"Single tap");
    UITouch *locationOfTap = tapRecognizer; //This doesn't work

    CGPoint touchLocation = [_tileMap convertTouchToNodeSpace:locationOfTap];
    //convertTouchToNodeSpace requires UITouch

    [_cat moveToward:touchLocation];
}
```

**FIXED CODE HERE - THIS ALSO FIXES INVERTED Y AXIS**

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[self convertToNodeSpace:[tapRecognizer locationInView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]]]];
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use the `locationInView:` method on UIGestureRecognizer. If you pass nil for the view, this method will return the location of the touch in the window.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView: _tileMap]
}
```

There is also a helpful delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`. Just make sure to implement  and set your tap gesture's delegate to self.

Keep a reference to the gesture recognizer.

```
@property UITapGestureRecognizer *theTapRecognizer;
```

Initiailze the gesture recognizer

```
_theTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(someMethod:)];
_theTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[someView addGestureRecognizer: _theTapRecognizer];
```

Listen for delegate methods.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [_tileMap convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    // use your CGPoint
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I need an UITouch for my `CGPoint touchLocation = [_tileMap convertTouchToNodeSpace:locationOfTap];` Where convertTouchToNodeSpace converts a UITouch.. Can this code be used in that way?

Comment: Could you just modify `convertTouchToNodeSpace:` method to take in a CGPoint?

Comment: I can't find out where its defined, hahaha

Comment: Command click on the method name. Or is it in a private framework?

Comment: No, its cocos2d, open source as it gets.

Comment: `- (CGPoint)convertTouchToNodeSpace:(UITouch *)touch
{
 CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
 point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];
 return [self convertToNodeSpace:point];
}
` It does not get happy when I change it to CGPoint

Comment: I tried that, how do I properly set the delegate to self? I declare it like this: `self.tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];
    [_tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_doubleTapRecognizer];
    
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:_tapRecognizer];`

Comment: You'll need to keep a reference to the gesture recognizer as a property or an instance variable.

Comment: Seems like I can actually pass a CGpoint with `CGPoint location = [tapRecognizer locationInView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];` directly to moveToward, and that the glitch is somewhere else.. :s Will accept your answer anyways, as it helped me.

Answer (score 17):

In Swift:

```
func handleFrontTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   print("tap working")
   if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Recognized
   { 
      print(gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
    oneFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTapDetected:)];
    oneFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    oneFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;

    [view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTap];
}

-(void)oneTapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"one tap detec");
    tapPositionOneFingerTap = [oneFingerTap locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f",tapPositionOneFingerTap.x,tapPositionOneFingerTap.y);
}
```

This prints the coordinates of each tap in your console.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624200-numberoftouches?language=objc) say

> UIGestureRecognizer
>
> ```
> - (NSUInteger)numberOfTouches
> ```
>
> The number of UITouch objects in a **private array** maintained by the receiver.

So you shouldn't access them.

> Using the value returned by this method in a loop, you can ask for the location of individual touches using the `locationOfTouch:inView:` method.