# Sprite Kit detect position of touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to run different actions depending on if you touch the left or right half of the screen. So an action when you touch the left half, and another when the right half is touched.

I suppose I could make a transparent button image that covers half of the screen and use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/spritekit-setting-up-buttons-in-skscene) to run an action when touched, but I don't think that's the way to go. Is there a better way to detect the position of a touch?

Comment: You can use a gesture recognizer instead of buttons. Then take the location of the touch event and determine where that point lies on the screen.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618109/how-to-get-uitouch-location-from-uigesturerecognizer

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think I came up with a pretty good solution. (see answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `touchesEnded:withEvent` or `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method to do this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch){
        if([touch locationInView:self.view]>self.size.width/2){
            [self runTouchOnRightSideAction];
        }else{
            [self runTouchOnLeftSideAction];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just found the solution and posted it a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: @user2255273 sorry about that, I was in the middle of writing my answer when you posted yours.

Comment: No problem, your version is cleaner! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following code and it works perfect.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // If left half of the screen is touched
    if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2) {
        // Do whatever..
    }

    // If right half of the screen is touched
    if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2) {
        // Do whatever..
    }
}
```