# How to get X and Y co-ordinate of image when i click ( swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

can any body suggest how can I get x and y coordinate of image in a mouse click or touch when I click in image that is inside image view.

Thanks

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer might do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618109/how-to-get-uitouch-location-from-uigesturerecognizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add on click gesture listener to your image view

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then in your handler, find the location of the tap in your image view in this way

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let cgpoint = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: imageView)

    print(cgpoint)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Subclass ...

It's very handy to do this in a subclass of an image...

```
class SegmentyImage: UIIImageView {

    override func common() {
        super.common()
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addGestureRecognizer(
          UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clicked)))
    }
    
    @objc func clicked(g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let p = g.location(in: self)
        print(p.x)
    }
}
```

In particular, imagine some sort of image which has on it (say) five parts to click on from left to right.

```
    @objc func clicked(g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let p = g.location(in: self)
        if self.frame.size.width <= 0 { return; }
        let segmentIndex: Int = Int( (p.x / self.frame.size.width) * 5.0 )
        print("section is .. \(segmentIndex)")
    }
```

You can now easily pass on the segment-clicked to the view controller.